# Prove onto homomorphism between $Z_n/ \rightarrow Z_k$ where $k | n$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Prove onto homomorphism between $Z_n/ \rightarrow  Z_k$ where $k | n$

Define $\phi:Z_n -> Z_k$

$\phi(x)=x\mod k \; \; \forall x \in Z_n$

Let $x=y$ $\Rightarrow x \mod k = y\mod k \Rightarrow \phi(x)=\phi(y) $

Therefore well defined

Now $\phi(a +_n b) = \phi(r) = r \mod k\; \; \;$ where $a+b = r \mod n$

now, $n|a+b-r \Rightarrow k|a+b-r \Rightarrow a+b=r \mod k \Rightarrow a +_k b = r$

Also $\phi(a)=a \mod k$

$\phi(b)=b \mod k$

$\phi(a) +_k \phi(b)= (a \mod k) +_k (b \mod k) = (a+_k b) \mod k = r \mod k =\phi(a+_n b)$

therefore homomorphism

now, $\forall y \in Z_k, \exists y \in Z_n \; such \; that \phi(y)= y \mod k = y
$

therefore onto

Is this proof correct ?

I particularly want to ask is the definition of my $\phi$ valid? I am asking this because I restricted the set of input values to $Z_n$ to make my proof simpler. So it this still valid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proof is correct. $\phi $ is valid. But you have written various simple steps but at one point where you said there exists $y \in k$ such that $\phi (y) = y$. You have not made it clear. Although it is correct.

Comment: is it always true that $(a \mod c) +_k (b \mod c) = (a +_k b) \mod c$

Comment: You can see it by some examples that it is not always true and try to find out conditions when they will be true.

Comment: only when $k|c$?